# OpenCV tiling TIFF image on loading with imread

Tags: python, opencv

I have a 32-bit 3-band TIF image that I am trying to load using OpenCV with Python. I'm specifically avoiding GDAL as it is not user-friendly to install on Windows, and this script is targeted at Windows machines.

When I try to load the image with imread (
`img = cv2.imread(file, flags=(cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED | cv2.IMREAD_ANYDEPTH))`
), and either write it out or imshow it, the 3 bands appear to be tiled, like so:
[image: uss_midway]

For comparison, rendering in Windows looks like this:
[image: windowsmidway]
So there should be no issue from an OS support perspective.

GIMP Properties for image:
[image: Properties pane from GIMP - RGB color, 32-bit gamma floating point]

Is there a way to override this behaviour? Is there a known cause to this?

Comment: look at https://forum.opencv.org/t/c-opencv-one-dimensional-array-to-image/5589 if you believe OpenCV is reading your TIFF incorrectly, open an issue on OpenCV's github (including data and [mre])

Comment: Post your input TIFF file!

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz That link looks like the same issue, but I don't know C++. It does confirm that probably something to do with the formatting of the image is the problem, though.

Comment: @fmw42 unfortunately the licensing on the image does not permit it being shared publicly as raw pixels

Comment: try creating something with imagemagick that has the same effect? the data is likely planar, but interpreted to be interleaved. also, the first plane has data, but the other two are black? seems like there are multiple issues (in OpenCV's handling of that file)

Comment: Can you open the file with ImageMagick or some other tool (GIMP or Photoshop) and view it correctly? Just as a test. Also you could try using Python Wand, which is based upon ImageMagick. If you can open fine in Python Wand, then you can convert from Wand format to OpenCV format.

Comment: Please open the file with irfanView or GIMP and post the properties like data format, color formst, etc.

Comment: I've posted the properties from GIMP. Opening it in GIMP and exporting from there does seem to make it compatible with OpenCV, so I suspect there may be something up in the source file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. Using the tifffile library in conjunction with scikit-image, I was able to load my TIFFs in a format understandable by OpenCV.

Thus, my load statement became:

```
img = skimage.io.imread(file,plugin='tifffile')
```

And the image:

[image]